# Changing button image with existing image shape

Tags: excel, vba

I have an ActiveX CommandButton in a WorkSheet, and I want to change the .picture property with an existing image called "ImgButtonMini" in another WorkSheet, that ISN'T ACTIVEX control (is a image shape)

I tried with:

```
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CmdUndoComboBoxes").Picture = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BASE").ImgButtonMini.Picture.
```

And system returns Error 438 (can't get / set that property)

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't change the background of a form control button. How does your form control button have a picture? Is it possibly a shape and not actually a form control?

Comment: Sorry again, I did a mistake editing the question: second control is an image shape, NOT a CommandButton

Comment: That makes much more sense, ok thanks for the edit.

Comment: I don't know if this is possible, haven't been able to figure it out. Is assigning the macro to just the image (and avoiding ActiveX controls entirely) an option?

Comment: I'm finishing the solution. Tomorrow, I will answer my own question